# Making a responsive UI without using a webview

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to develop Android applications
I am good in Java
But not good in designing XML UIs

There are lot of UI frameworks which use webviews.
but i am not interested in it

Is there any framework which deals with only XML part?
Or anything which can convert Html to Android XML?

The point is I just want the XML part

Is it possible?

Comment: Whatever you can do with XML in android you can also do with JAVA in android. The XML in android and HTML are totally different things. And by the way XML in android are not fixed you can extend `View` sub classes and  make your own XML too!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use constraint layout or Relative layout for this. My choice is use constraint layout for best UI.